# Bioinformatics databases with negative results?

Tags: database, resources, dataset, bioinformatics

Bioinformatics databases such as BioGRID collect a lot of interaction results for proteins and genes in different species from all sorts of publications and experiments, but such collations sufer from testing biases since not all combinations are tested, and some are tested more than once. Shouldn't they also collect all negative results? Is there such a resource which systematically collects both positive and negative interactions from High Throughput and Low Throughput experiments?

Comment: There is a stack-exchange for bioinformatics-related questions called Biostar.  Google "stackexchange biostar" to find it.  You will probably get better answers there.

Comment: @nedblof, I didn't know about that. Perhaps this should be migrated to biostar. I am not sure how to initiate a migration.

Comment: I'm not sure how to migrate nor do I think I have the clearance for that operation.  Probably best just to cut and paste your question.  The folks on biostar have been very helpful in answering my bioinformatics-related questions.

Comment: The way to request migration to another stack-exchange site is to use the "flag" link to request moderator attention. This is much preferred to duplicating the question between sites (known as 'cross-posting' and very frowned upon). I have flagged this question for moderator attention.

Comment: @Will: To [Biostar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @gotgenes: Can't migrate there.  Its a StackExchange 1.0 site.  That site (and others like it) is from back during the initial expansion of the StackExchange network.  They are pretty much abandoned; they don't participate in migration like the StackExchange 2.0 sites that emerged from Area51.  If you want, you can crosspost there (crossposting on SE 2.0 sites is not allowed because we can migrate questions to those sites).

Comment: @Will: I'll leave it up to the original author. Thanks for looking into the migration.

Comment: I personally think this is one of the most important questions (and a challenge in general) to building reliable automated protein-protein interaction prediction software. It's a question that has haunted me since my masters.

Answer (score 2):

These might help:

http://www.jnrbm.com/info/about/

http://www.jnr-eeb.org/index.php/jnr

and so far I know databases of non-hitters or non-binding drug-like compounds exist

Answer (score 2):

You should look for the '[Negatome](http://mips.helmholtz-muenchen.de/proj/ppi/negatome/)', database of non-interacting protein pairs.

Smialowski P, Pagel P, Wong P, Brauner B, Dunger I, Fobo G, Frishman G,
Montrone C, Rattei T, Frishman D, Ruepp A. The Negatome database: a reference set
of non-interacting protein pairs. Nucleic Acids Res. 2010 Jan;38(Database
issue):D540-4. Epub 2009 Nov 17. PubMed PMID: 19920129; PubMed Central PMCID:
PMC2808923. Available from: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19920129

Answer (score 0):

1) High throughput screens that are published in peer reviewed journals often have such data.  Cessarini has published negative results regaring domain/peptide interactions.
2) You can contact data bases like mint/reactome/etc... and mention that you want the negative results where they are available.  Many such organizations are required by mandate to share any such data with you, even if its not on their site.
3) A good resource on this subject is here http://www.nature.com/nmeth/journal/v4/n5/full/nmeth0507-377.html

Answer (score 0):

We have been working on an opensource protein interactions meta-database & prediction server (which does include data from BioGRID among other sources) that deals with both negative and positive data as you have asked for...

***MAYETdb*** does the following:

1. Classify protein interactions as either "interacting" or "not interacting"
2. Includes data from a variety of experimental set-ups (Y2H, TAP-MS, more) and species (yeast, human, c.elegans) (inc. both literature-mined and databased data e.g. BioGRID).
3. It also yields false-positive and false-negative errors of those classifications.
4. Random forest machine learning system makes predictions for previously un-tested interactions by learning form a wide variety of protein features and works at rather high accuracy (~92% AUG).

It is not yet running on a server but the source code is available and heavily commented if you are curiously impatient: https://bitbucket.org/dknightg/ppidb/src

**Please ask if you have any queries :)**